# Gatling, Karate and classic feeders

Tags: karate

How can I use classic gatling feeders in our karate features? I mean I don't want to feed all the users with the same data in Scenario Examples, and I'd like to use a feeder so that each user has a unique record. Is is possible to do?

Comment: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/551 - please add some information there so that the community can help build this

Comment: sure, I did it. I consider this can help in how to configure our tests so that we'll not have problems sharing data among all the users.